# Linq to SQL - Populating an IEnumerable property

Tags: linq-to-sql, collections, ienumerable

I am trying to pull some records from a table (BidNames) and pass them to a view in a view model.  My view model consists of nothing more than a collection of BidName records.

My view model:

```
public class BidNamesVM
{
    public IEnumerable<BidName> BidNames { get; set; }
}
```

I'm having problems populating the BidNames collection.  The conversion from bn to BidNames isn't working.

```
from bn in BidNames
where bn.CustomerID == 1160 && bn.Customer.Bids.Any(b=>b.Item.AuctionID == 2)
select new BidNamesVM
{
    BidNames = bn 
}
```

What do I have to do to populate BidNames in my query?

Many thanks,

BK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your LINQ query already returns an `IEnumerable<BidName>`, with `bn` representing an individual instance of `BidName`.  Try this:

```
BidNamesVM bnVM = new BidNamesVM();
bnVM.BidNames = from bn in BidNames
                where bn.CustomerID == 1160 && bn.Customer.Bids.Any(b=>b.Item.AuctionID == 2)
                select bn;
```

In your example, you were trying to set an instance of `BidName` to a property of type `IEnumerable<BidName>`, which won't work for obvious reasons.